# How to prevent JavaScript files to be cached in IIS

Tags: caching, iis, iis-7.5

I have a weird problem, javascript files are cached in IIS,

What I have done till now

- Disabled caching on my website in IIS
  [image: Disabled caching on my website in IIS]
- Disable cache on chrome dev tools
  [image]
- Adding timespan at url in page to prevent any chaching
  [image]
- Doubled check to see if the files on disk are updated and they were updated

But my scripts and css not updating from latest version on disk, until I do IISReset

Comment: How do you confirm that the updates are not happening? Are you totally sure that there is not another IIS website that you are using instead - like you have one on localhost but another on the static IP? Longshots.

Comment: @VanquishedWombat I right click on my page view source and click the js file link there and then search for my change (and do the same for the file on my drive) and changes are not there.
Yeah, so I am sure it's my local IIS because when I change the html files it will reflected on my site,
p.s When I do IISReset files are updated

Answer (score 0):

Your attempt to break the cache is short circuited by the fact you are getting the cached version of the content page with the old timestamp, meaning you never request the JavaScript page with the new timestamp until something else forces the content page to reload.

You can check this by using the same cache breaking scheme on the content page itself in addition to the JavaScript page.

This is not a recommended solution as you will bypass cache altogether for the content page.

Every answer I've seen for this problem has worked sometimes and other times not.  If I get a solution, I'll post it.